# How to pull the exact animation mentioned in the Hammer.js homepage

Tags: javascript, android, hammer.js

I want to know how exactly to get [this output](https://cdn.rawgit.com/hammerjs/hammer.js/master/tests/manual/visual.html). Mentioned in the Hammer.js homepage itself. I tried to do it by copying the same code and while emulating, I get the event notifications as 'spanleft' or 'panright'. But my div does not move or animate like shown there. What am I missing? Any HTML5 animation?

EDIT : [I'm adding a fiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/e8pd8xvc/) When I debug it in my phone using phonegap method, it does identifies my multi-touch pinch and rotate actions and appends the value to a preset

`<p id="text"></p>`

However image stays static. It doesn't change position or size.

Comment: Could you share some code of yours?

Comment: check edit please. @Volker E